# jstree - searching for a node returns the complete jstree

Tags: search, jstree

I use the following code to search for a specific node text:

```
$("#create_1").click(function () {
  node = $("#patterneditor").jstree("search", "report");
  node.css("font-weight", "bold");
```

});

Here is the part from the html-data tree:

```
<li rel="hashkey" class="jstree-open">
  <a href="#">report</a>
  <ul>
    <li rel="hash" class="jstree-open"><a href="#">Hash</a>
      <ul>
```

But when executing the search and applying the css-settings all tree nodes become bold.
The "report"-node becomes italic (so i think the search worked below a given point), but I want to have the node object stored in the node variable.
Does anyone know why this happens and how this can get fixed?

Regards
Tristan

Comment: Don't you want to use built-in search function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that the search-functionality is not able to get the object of the node I've searched. Instead i used something like

```
node = $("#patterneditor").jstree("select_node", $("[pattern_section='pattern']"));
$("#patterneditor").jstree("create", node);
```

holy cow ..